# SpringMVC is not recognizing request body parameters if using PUT

Tags: jquery, rest, spring-mvc

Maybe this is supposed to not work, but at least I'd like to understand why then. I am passing a simple val=somevalue in the `PUT` body but spring sends back a `400 Bad Request` as it does not seem to recognise the val parameter.

Similar request works with `POST`. Could it be *SpringMVC* is not recognizing the `PUT` request body as source for parameters?

`Content=-Type` is set correctly to application/x-www-form-urlencoded in both cases.

The method that spring refuses to call is this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "config/{key}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public void configUpdateCreate(final Model model, @PathVariable final String key, @RequestParam final String val,
        final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    //...
}
```

For completeness, here is the jquery ajax call. I cannot see anything wrong with that. Client is Firefox 4 or Chrome, both show the same result.

```
$.ajax({
         url:url,
         type:'PUT',
         data:'val=' + encodeURIComponent(configValue),
         success: function(data) {...}
       });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: does it work when you change the it to POST?

Comment: Why do you annotate the method with @ResponseBody in a void method? That annotation is supposed to indicate that the return type should be written straight to the HTTP response body. I think this is not the case. You could try to do this as well: data:{'val', encodeURIComponent(configValue)},

Comment: What is the error message that comes back with the 400 code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know of a work around at this point, but here is the bug report that is a "Won't Fix."  I've been fighting the same issue

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7414

Update:  Here is my fix.  I'm using RequestBody annotation.  Then using MultiValueMap.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{tc}", method = RequestMethod.PUT) 
public void update(@PathVariable("tc") final String tc, 
@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String,String> body, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String name = body.getFirst("name");
// more code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the discussion on the Tomcat list, it clarifies the issue. In my case the solution with the @RequestBody annotation didn't work with a custom model/form-backing-bean class, rather than a multimap. So I'm using the HiddenHttpMethodFilter and I'm sending a POST request from jQuery including a _method=put param instead, as php-coder suggested.

Answer (score 12):

[Since](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5628) Spring 3.1, this is resolved using [org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HttpPutFormContentFilter.html).

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpPutFormContentFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpPutFormContentFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: this will go into your web.xml

Answer (score 1):

I don't have right solution for you, but in your case I try following:

- create page with `form:form method="PUT"`
- declare `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` in `web.xml`

If this will works, then

- change `type` from `PUT` to `POST` in ajax call
- add needed params which client has with `form:form` tag (something like `_method`)

In other words, as I understand Spring emulates `PUT` based on simple `POST` with special parameter. Just send to him what he wants.

See also: http://stsmedia.net/spring-finance-part-2-spring-mvc-spring-30-rest-integration/ and related code examples there: http://code.google.com/p/spring-finance-manager/source/browse

HTH

Answer (score 1):

This, as suggest above, seems to be a bug in `spring/servlet API`. In reality `PUT` requests are supposed to work on `Request Body (or payload)` and not on Request Parameters. In that sense, servlet API & spring's handling is correct.

Having said that, a better and much easier workaround is to pass no data element from your `javascript/jQuery` call and pass your parameters as part of the url itself. meaning, set parameters in the url field the way you would do in a `GET` call.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "yoururl" + "?param1=param2Val&..",
            type: "PUT",
            data: "",
            success: function(response) {
                // ....
            }
     });
```

now this works for simple parameters, i guess, will not work for complex JSON types. Hope this helps.