# Spring 3.0 MVC Data Binding with HTTP PUT

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring

I have a simple Spring 3.0 controller with a PUT request mapping

```
@Controller
public class FooController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public @ResponseBody FooView put(@PathVariable String id, @Valid PutFoo putFoo, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        inspector.inspect(bindingResult);
        return fooService.update(id, putFoo);
    }
}
```

When I execute a PUT with `Foo` parameters in the request body, the PutFoo object is not being populated/binded with that data. If I add HttpServletRequest to the method signature and print the body of the request, sure enough the data is there but `PutFoo` is empty.

If I change the request method type to POST and then execute a POST, this all works harmoniously.

For completeness, I'm hitting the endpoint via cURL with
    `curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -X PUT -F "fooString=foo" http://localhost:8080/foo/9999`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894270/springmvc-is-not-recognizing-request-body-parameters-if-using-put
This question seems to hit close to the mark, though I'm not getting rejected with a HTTP 400. I think the JIRA linked in the answer may be my answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are actually sending a http PUT request since you are using conflicting curl parameters. For instance

> -F, --form
>
> (HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has
>   pressed the submit button. This causes curl to **POST** data using the
>   Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388.

[source](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: Well, it's certainly making into the method annotated with RequestMethod.PUT, I'll run this through a proxy, perhaps the full HTTP request may be of use.

Comment: Yeah, so this is user error - Compared two requests via a proxy; one using the above cURL command, the other less the `-F "fooString=foo"` and adding the parameters as URL parameters. Second worked! Looking at the proxy output, the Content-Type on the second was as specified but the first also had `boundary=....` which as you say indicates multipart/form-data and its data was in the body.