# PUT and POST - same parameter but bad request for PUT

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-post, spring-restcontroller, http-put

I have Post method and Put method for requestMapping("projects").

```
@PutMapping
public ResponseEntity<ResultDomain> updateProjet(@RequestParam String projectJSON,
        @RequestParam MultipartFile image, @RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile image1,
        @RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile image2) throws Exception {
}

@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<ResultDomain> addProjet(@RequestParam String projectJSON, @RequestParam MultipartFile image,
        @RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile image1, @RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile image2)
        throws Exception {
}
```

These 2 method have exactly the same parameter. When i request for POST, I have no problem with it. But when i request for PUT, it will return bad request. Is there any restriction for PUT method?

POSTMAN RESULT:

**POST METHOD**
[image]

**PUT METHOD**
[image]

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you paste the stack trace or error message if any?

Comment: too bad there is no stack trace...it didn't went into the method and reject with bad request

Comment: Please enable debug mode and send the request. Hope there will be some stacktrace

Comment: I have tried debug mode...still there's no stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I'm able to solve it by replace `@RequestParam String projectJSON` to `@RequestPart String projectJSON`. Still don't know why though..can anyone explain? Thanks for the kind answer..appreciated it

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue a few months ago while working on a RESTful Service.

Adding the [HttpPutFormContentFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HttpPutFormContentFilter.html) helped me resolve this issue.

**Reference:** [SpringMVC Not Recognizing Body Parameters While Using PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894270/springmvc-is-not-recognizing-request-body-parameters-if-using-put)

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. How do i add HttpPutFormContentFilter to a spring boot rest project? Most of the website i found add inside web.xml which i don't have